# How to draw curved and straight lines using d3.js path generator?

Tags: javascript, html, svg, d3.js

I am trying to draw a thermometer shape with a d3 path generator instead of hard coding it in the HTML. I have been able to draw straight lines **or** curved lines using a d3 path generator, but I need to be able to do both to get this shape. Here is what I have hard coded in HTML.

```
<path d ="  M 50,35 
                    L 50,400
                    A 50 50, 0, 1, 0, 95 400
                    L 95,35
                    A 25 25, 0, 0, 0, 50 35" />
```

Comment: D3 path generators aren't suitable for drawing specific kinds of shapes.

Comment: What is the best way to draw it with d3 then instead of hard coding it in the html?

Comment: I don't see any reason not to hardcode it. You could also keep the value of the `d` attribute as a variable and apply as needed.

Comment: What would be the best way to resize it if it is hard coded? hard code different size options and plug them in based on the users input?

Comment: try this http://roadtolarissa.com/blog/2015/02/22/svg-path-strings/

Comment: Just apply a `transform` with a `scale(2)` or something like that.

Comment: If you are resizing the container like maximize/minimize, you can use viewbox. See [ViewBox and ViewPort](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/svg/svg-viewport-view-box.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get it to work by applying a `transform` with a `scale()`.

```
if(size=="small")
     shape.attr('transform', "scale(.5)");
else if(size=="large")
     shape.attr('transform', "scale(2)");
```

Thank you Lars Kotthoff for giving the answer.